# differences between two SQL Server database snapshots

Tags: sql-server, database

I am trying to automate order processing for a client
their POS vendor doesn't have any sort of API with their software
so I was hoping to be able to insert orders directly in the database.

so what i want to do is take a snapshot of the database, enter an order manually and then take another snapshot and compare the 2 snapshots to see what has been  done.

is there a tool around that can analyse the two SQL Server snapshots and output an sql file of the differences ?

please don't lecture me about this being a bad idea, i already know the risks
of messing with someone elses data directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [SQLDelta](http://www.sqldelta.com/) should work for you.

Comment: Looks it's only schema comparison tool, not the whole snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

Many years later...
Redgate SQL Data Compare will do this now, free trial and all. Can compare between backup files, live dbs, snapshots etc.